# What is the right algorithm to solve a partition with extra constraints?

Tags: algorithm, constraints, partitioning

Here is a summary of my problem:

I have a set of problems that needs to be assigned to a set a people. Each problem should only be assigned to a person and all problems should be assigned (partition). Each problem has a value (continuous variable) and a cost (the cost is different for different people, each pair person-problem has its own cost).

The goal is to find a partition that assigns problems to people so that for each person the maximum cost across all assigned problems is lower than a certain threshold and all partitions have roughly the same total value (or better the difference between the total values across people is minimized).

Could anyone point me to the right direction? I know there are greedy algorithms to solve the multi-way partition problem but I don't know how they can be modified to deal with the extra constraint that maximum cost across all problems assigned to a person should be lower than a certain threshold.

Is it something that could be solved with a constraint modeling language like minizinc?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

From your description I'm not sure you have a *partition problem*, but an *assignment problem*, since you are trying to assign to each problem a person.

Below I share with you a basic [MiniZinc](http://minzinc.org) model that should capture your problem roughly; you probably need to make some adaptions to fully fit your problem description.

problem.mzn:

```
 int: num_people;  % the number of people
 set of int: PEOPLE = 1..num_people;
 int: num_problems; % the number of problems
 set of int: PROBLEMS = 1..num_problems;
 array[PROBLEMS] of float: value;  % the value of each problem
 array[PROBLEMS, PEOPLE] of float: cost; % the cost of each problem, for each person
 float: threshold; % the threshold for the overall costs

 % DECISION VARIABLE: assign to each problem a person
 array[PROBLEMS] of var PEOPLE: personForProblem;


 % the sum of the costs of the "problem-person" assignment must be smaller than a threshold 
 constraint 
    sum (problem in PROBLEMS) (cost[problem, personForProblem[problem]] )  
    <= threshold;

 % maximize the sum of the value of each "problem-person" assignment
 solve maximize 
     sum (problem in PROBLEMS) ( value[personForProblem[problem]]);
```

In this model, I first define all the *parameters* you have defined: the number of people, `num_people`, the number of problems, `num_problems`, the `value` of each problem, and the `cost` for each problem, which varies per person, and the `threshold` for the overall costs.

Second, I define the *decision variables*, `personForProblem` which is an array of integer variables where the integer represents the person to which the problem is assigned to.

Third, I post the *constraint* that the sum of all costs has to be smaller than the `threshold`.

Finally, I state that the problem *objective* is to maximise the overall `value`. Not sure if this is your objective, you have not specified what the purpose of `value` is, so this is a guess.

If you save the text above into a file `problem.mzn` then you can solve this problem model using MiniZinc with a sample data file, for instance:

sample-problem.dzn:

```
num_people = 4;
num_problems = 3;

value = [  3.0,  7.2, 1.2 ];

cost = array2d(PROBLEMS, PEOPLE, 
    [ 
      2.3, 6.2, 1.2, 4.2, % cost for the 4 people for problem-1
      5.1, 3.2, 2.3, 7.8, % cost for the 4 people for problem-2
      1.5, 1.7, 4.2, 1.2, % cost for the 4 people for problem-3
    ]);

threshold = 10.0;
```

I hope this helps to fully formulate your problem.